# Issues with MySQL inserting columns below desired location

Tags: mysql

I have been having some frustration attempting to add data values to this table students. I have all the other data values and have dropped and created the column student_id. However, when trying to add the data with this query:

```
insert into students(student_id) values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5');
```

The data does not insert correctly, as it creates new columns below the first 5 which contain data.

It must be because of my not null values, but I can't not have the not null identifier.

Is there a query command that allows me to change data within already existing value-filled columns? I have been unsuccessful in finding this so far.

Here are some images to explain the problem further.

1. [The query I have made to add my values to the table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2tex.png)
2. [The data was inserted but as it is underneath the columns I need to map with a foreign key, I cannot use the column as the top 5 values are still my not null default, which is required to let me create the foreign key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D28K.png)

Comment: Are you trying to set the student_id's of the currently existing students to 1,2,3,...?

Comment: yes, up to 5 - it is an id column to correspond with the columns of data used along it.

Comment: Can you show the table schema?

Comment: "*it creates new columns*" new rows maybe? Or maybe instead of `values (1),(2),...` to create 5 rows you actually meant `values (1,2,3,4,5)` to create one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have your records initially created without the student_id field, you want to UPDATE the current records but you're actually INSERTING new records.

You're meant to update your students with update statements such as "UPDATE students SET student_id = X where condition = Y"

Then it looks like your student_id is your primary key which you should set to AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Regards

Comment: Brilliant! I have heard about the update function and it does work, I'm just figuring out how to delete lots of null and not null default rows.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT is the wrong command since you want to update existing rows. The problem here lies within the fact that the order of the rows is nondeterministic and I think you cannot update them in one statement. One solution would be as follows:

```
 UPDATE students SET student_id = 1 WHERE first_name = 'Berry';
 UPDATE students SET student_id = 2 WHERE first_name = 'Darren';
```

I hope you really do have only 5 columns to update :-)

Comment: I don't have any more columns at the moment so it should be fine. Thank you for helping me!